# Grails Build Fails While Resolving Dependencies

Tags: maven, grails, jenkins, ivy, artifactory

I've got a build that fails when running it via SSH with the following issue:

```
WARN: problem while downloading module descriptor:

http://[internal_artifactory]:8081/artifactory/repo/org/grails/plugins/[plugin]/1.0/[plugin]-1.0.pom

Access is denied (156ms)
```

I have checked the Artifactory logs and see that the download was 'accepted' so it's not an authentication issue on that end (besides, Artifactory is set up to allow anonymous downloads).  If I check the ivy cache I see that an `ivy-1.0.xml.original.part` file is created, but nothing else is downloaded.  I've checked the permissions on that directory and the user that Jenkins runs as as well as the SSH user both have full permission to the ivy-cache directory.  I'm at a loss here - if I run it straight up on the server it works fine, but calling it via SSH from Jenkins bombs out.

Comment: Did you try to raise the resolution log level - http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#debuggingResolution ?